# git push error - undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b

Tags: ssh, git

I have a git repository on an external hard drive mounted on `/run/media/<myusername>/<drivename>`. When I try to push the code to the online github repo with `git push -u origin master` I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3: undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Thinking that something was broken in krb5-libs or git, I tried pushing another different repo located in my `/home/<username>` folder but it worked.

What's wrong with having repositories on an external hard drive? How could I fix the previous error?

I'm on Fedora 32 Kernel 5.6.18-300.fc32.x86_64.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're seeing here is that the version of the Kerberos 5 libraries and the version of OpenSSL you're using are incompatible.

On most distros, OpenSSH is compiled with Kerberos 5 support.  The libraries used for cryptography for Kerberos are linked with OpenSSL in your case.

The reason pushing to another repo in your home directory works is because Git doesn't use the `ssh` command for that and hence you don't see any problems.  If you tried to use `ssh` to log into another system, you would see the same problem.  There is nothing intrinsically wrong with having repositories on another drive, either; that's a red herring.

You should reinstall the `krb5-libs` and `openssl` packages first, and see if that works.  If you've installed any local copies of OpenSSL or Kerberos (look in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib64`), then delete them and run `ldconfig`.

You may also find it instructive to run `ldd $(which ssh)` to find the locations of any libraries that OpenSSH is using, and delete any which are not shipped by Fedora.

Comment: I discovered that in order to use a specific command line tool, I sourced a bash file that changes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` via export command. I solved it by simply opening another terminal tab where these environment variables were correct.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DarthVi, Same issue. I also changed the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Even on "correctly" configured systems, this and similar error messages may be caused by temporary changes to the system environment. This intermittent behavior can be confusing to troubleshoot, but reverting or avoiding the problematic environment changes should correct the issue.

Examples:

- On SLURM systems, `module load`-ing certain software may mis-configure the environment for git, yielding this error. If loading a module causes this error, `module del <the_module>` should resolve the problem.
- OP's issue was caused by modifying environment variables. A "fresh" terminal session (with original env configuration) corrected the issue, as would reverting the affected environment variables.

Comment: The SLURM note helped me. Specifically, the anaconda3 module that I was loading was causing the error.

Comment: This was exactly my issue too. In my case, it was the `miniconda/3` slurm module that I was loading in my `~/.bashrc` that was causing the error. I unloaded the miniconda module, and the git commands work fine now.